# Windows Phone 8.1 MainPage Frame.navigate

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I'm creating a Windows Phone 8.1 app.

I'm OK with simple navigation using 
`Frame.navigate(typeof(mypage));` and it seems to be working fine.

- I want to do some database processing on `MainPage` then when finished go to `Page1`.
- Using an event handler on button click works fine but I've put the navigation code at the end of the `OnNavigatedTo` function after my processing.
  Page1 doesn't load, although a debug writeline statement before and after both work so I know it's running.

I'm sure there is an obvious reason or fix, could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

try wrap the navigation code in

```
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
// Navigate to page 1 here
});
```